# How does Calanolide A react with NaOH solution?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, aromatic-compounds

Calanolide A is an anti-HIV drug

[image: Calanolide A Molecular Structure]

I assume the ester group, phenolic hydroxyl group and carboxyl group formed by hydrolysis in the molecule can react with NaOH. Is that correct?

How many moles of NaOH will be consumed when reacting with 1 mole of Calanolide A?

Comment: Remove the last para as it is a HW question unless you have done some effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coumarins are hydrolysed by hydroxide as described in this [paper](https://www.scirp.org/pdf/aces_2013071111180355.pdf)

Coumaric acid contains a phenol and a carboxylic acid group and can consume 2 eqs of hydroxide, though hydrolysis can occur with only 1 eq giving the salt of the carboxylic acid and the phenol un-ionised. It is important to not overcook the reaction as the coumarin/cinnamic acid group is able to degrade under strong base conditions.